# Cluster or classify tree species data into distinct categories

Tags: clustering, spatial, ecology

I'm an experienced data analyst who is unfortunately ignorant about statistical techniques and clustering. I'm looking for help in identifying the best technique to solve the problem below.

A cross tabulation sample of my data is pasted below: in short I have 6,500 survey plots with tree species records (% polygon cover) for each plot. There are 14 species in total.

How do I go about classifying these polgyons into distinct groups? Clearly the 14 species are not randomly distributed, so there will be common patterns and associations across the dataset. But how do I go about identifying these commonalities over 14 variables? What kind of test or procedure do I need to read up on?

Once I have identified initial groupings, I can then share these with a tree expert who can hopefully translate them into rules such as "if polygon > 80 species X -> Category 1 etc"

I use Alteryx for my data manipulation, and it has various tools such as K centroids, see https://help.alteryx.com/10.6/index.htm#Getting_Started/AllTools.htm#Predictive_Grouping

I would be grateful if you could suggest what type of analysis I need to pursue. I'm guessing it must be pretty common, and I'm sorry for being ignorant. Hopefully someone can point me the right direction. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This looks like a spatial problem, there must be spatial correlation in the data.

Comment: You're correct, but in the first instance I want to ignore the spatial element to focus purely on the categorisation. I want to present my ecological domain expert with the most common 'clusters' of species observed in the data. Then he can fine tune the decision tree based on those initial clusters

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're interested in some kind of hierarchical clustering here. Take a look at the `hclust` function, it will do the work of producing a classification tree. 
However, your data seem to have many zeros, so you'll need to use a proper data transformation to deal with that, take a look at the `vegan::decostand` function and the `hellinger` transformation. 
Sometimes, it's not so easy to find the best limit to define the groupings, using Bootstrap can help, take a look at the `pvclust` package.